# How to show that in Solow's model competitive labour markets and the assumption of constant returns to scale imply that the wage is positive?

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth

I would like to know if you could help me to solve this exercise from *Acemoglu's book "Introduction to Modern Economic Growth"*

**Exercise 2.1 : Show that competitive labor markets and Assumption 1 imply that the wage rate must be strictly positive and thus (2.4) implies (2.3)**

Assumption 1:
[image]

[image]

$$L(t)=\bar L(t)\;\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;\;\;\; (2.3)$$

I've been thinking about it for a few days, but I really don't know where to start. I would be very grateful for your help

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the wage rate is strictly positive depends on the assumption of **competitive markets** and on the assumption of **strictly positive marginal** **products** (and, of course, on the assumption that $F$  is differentiable)$^1$.  In particular, the marginal product of labour is (**Assumption 1**):

$$ F_L(K,L, A)\equiv \frac {\partial F(K,L, A)}{\partial L} >0$$

We know that in a competitive market, in equilibrium, the wage rate is equal to the marginal productivity of labour$^2$:

$$w=F_L(K,L, A)\equiv \frac {\partial F(K,L, A)}{\partial L} >0\;\;\;\; \;\;(1)$$

so $w$ is strictly positive.

As $w>0$, so $w\neq 0$, we have that $(2.4)$ implies $(2.3)$. Indeed, $(2.4)$ states:

$$(L(t))-\bar L(t)) w(t) =0.^3\;\;\;\;\; (2.4)$$

As $w\neq 0$,  to satisfy this equality, must be

$$L(t))-\bar L(t) =0, $$

that is

$$L(t))=\bar L(t).\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2.3) $$

---

$^1$ <sup>Constant returns to scale play no role here. They  will be important later in the model, because they allow to write the *intensive production function*</sup>

$^2$ <sup>You can remember from microeconomic theory that, in a competitive market, the profit maximizing firms equate the value of the marginal product of a factor input to its price, in particular equate marginal productivity of labour to the wage rate. See also Acemoglu, *cit.* p.33, where you find the formula $(1)$ I wrote above.</sup>

$^3$  <sup>$\bar L(t)$ stands for the (anelastic with respect to wage) supply of labour.</sup>